# Mixed content ad

Tags: support, advertising, ssl

I'm seeing mixed content due to an ad.

[image: Mixed content address bar]

The offending host is `idsync.rlcdn.com` while delivering a 1x1 pixel.

I *believe* this is the offending ad. Tracking down these tracking pixels is a little tricky for me.

[image]

Comment: what does this mean if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @snb Oh, that's a great question - sorry for not explaining it earlier. Mozilla [has a great explanation of mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content). The gist of it is Stack Overflow (and all the other Q&A sites) use HTTPS to protect information in transit. However, an Advertisement got included that added non-HTTPS content. This non-HTTPS content undermines the purpose of HTTPS and its effectiveness, which is why browsers display some kind of warning sign when encountering it.

Comment: thanks for explaining! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Good work and I suggest to migrate your comment into your answer

Comment: Ironic that an ad about security is tripping up security... Human error or clever marketing strategy?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We have paused this campaign until the advertiser removes or fixes this pixel.

Update: The advertiser has disabled this content and the campaign is live again.

Answer (score 29):

A [twitter discussion](https://twitter.com/vcsjones/status/1011613614057426944?s=21) led to `upgrade-insecure-requests` being deployed on all Q&A sites. All requests will automatically get updated to https: if the browser supports this directive, which all modern browsers do.

This should address the issue in a more permanent way.

Comment: Sidenote, the browser extension [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) by the Electronic Frontier Foundation adds this functionality to every website on the internet. It allows you to block every non-encrypted request and tries to load all normal http request over https whenever possible.