# Mixed content due to ads

Tags: support, advertising, ssl

There is mixed (https and http) content appearing occasionally to me.

It *seems* to appear at the same time, but maybe not always as it couldn't catch it again a couple of days ago when I first noticed it, as an ad for Tesco:

[image: The ad]

The URL requested is

`http://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=19&mc=imp&pli=29957092&PluID=0&ord=1433594164&rtu=-1`

The response for the URL is:

> HTTP/1.1 200
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
> Pragma: no-cache
> Content-Type: image/gif
> Expires: Sun, 05-Jun-2005 22:00:00 GMT
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
> Set-Cookie: S_29957092=534465219734297496; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-2020 20:53:00 GMT
> A6=03Hj19tud5000CsY000000000; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-2020 04:53:00 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/
> eyeblaster=; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/
> u2=047dafd5-f688-4514-8ec9-d3bf62e7c2644xi080; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-2020 04:53:00 GMT; domain=.serving-sys.com; path=/
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> P3P: CP="NOI DEVa OUR BUS UNI"
> Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 08:53:16 GMT
> Content-Length: 42

The ad is in an `<iframe>`:

```html
<iframe style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: bottom;" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-37/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/248424177/stackoverflow.com/sb/question-pages_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" data-google-container-id="1" data-load-complete="true" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0">
```

so perhaps setting `upgrade-insecure-requests`, as mentioned in [Mixed content ad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370196/1115360), is ineffective for this.

**More information:** `http://bs.serving-sys.com` tells us that it "is a Sizmek Advertising Server". Following the link to the Sizmek home page tells us that it is "Sizmek by Amazon", so perhaps it is not associated with what appears to be an ad served by Google.

Comment: Isn't this an excellent way to filter out companies you probably don't want to work for? If they don't care about this, what are the other things they don't care about?

Comment: [I know of an easy fix for that](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)

Comment: @Zoe Even Adblock Plus would have blocked it. I don't mind ads being on the same page for some sites if it contributes towards site costs.

Comment: @ivarni I assume you mean Google in this case, as it appears that Tesco are an innocent victim here?

Comment: @AndrewMorton If it's Google that are still running traffic over insecure connections then sure. That's another red-flag in a long list of red flags when it comes to working for them.